# Memory allocation when just declare a variable of a class type

Tags: java

In Java, when we only declare a variable of a class type, only a reference is created (memory is not allocated for the object). Is to hold the reference t somewhere space will be created on heap ? or if i'm wrong then what happens exactly in memory when we just declare variable ?

```
Test t;
```

Comment: Is your question the following?:

*If I write `int a;` , will it allocate memory?*

Comment: Actually not...i am talking on the declaration of class type reference variable t of class Test type.

Answer (score 8):

> In Java, when we only declare a variable of a class type, only a reference is created (memory is not allocated for the object).

This is correct.

> Is to hold the reference t somewhere space will be created on heap?

The answer depends on the context in which the declaration appears. If the said declaration is part of an object (i.e. `t` is a *field*) then the space for the reference would be allocated from the heap, along with the space for the rest of the object containing the field. Otherwise, the space for the reference would be allocated in JVM's stack frame.

Comment: could you please tell the meaning of "If the said declaration is part of an object (i.e. t is a field)". in my question t is a reference variable of class Test (which may contain a field say int a)

Comment: @Naveen I mean something like this: `class MyClass { Test t; /*more stuff*/ }`

Comment: thanks not it clear.....but what would be the memory size of the reference variable(t) as the actual memory for the objects will be allocated when the reference is initialized with new operator like    t = new Test();

Comment: @Naveen The *size* of the reference variable is not going to change with the assignment, only its *value* would become different. The allocation with `new` is going to allocate `Test` on the heap, and put the address of the newly allocated object into the space that has been previously allocated to variable `t`.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a variable:

```
Test t;
```

space is made for the reference (a fixed amount, doesn't depend on the number of members in the class). When you *instantiate* a variable, using the **new** keyword:

```
t = new Test();
```

then space for the *variable* is made on the heap, and `t` references that space. This has to be large enough to hold all the members of a `Test`.

Comment: @P45Imminent You are not supposed to downvote every answer except the best one. Downvotes are for bad answers and upvotes are for good answers, regardless of what other answers there are out there.

You are free to do what you want, but what you are doing is counterproductive for both yourself and for the people writing the answers.

Comment: I agree but this answer adds nothing that the other answer adds. It's incomplete, doesn't mention the case when the declaration is a field of a class. i.e. it's not good. Really I think the upvoter should justify their actions.